# Cannot move up custom UIView when keyboard appears

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I have some issues with moving a custom UIView, an alert basically, up.
When I open the keyboard, everything works fine and the alert moves up as it should.
However, as soon as I digit something in the textField the alert falls back to its original position.
I have no clue why this is happening. BTW, alert view is added in storyboard and constrained to the center.
I have attached some explanatory images
Thanks in advance.

```
class AlertViewController: UIViewController {
       @IBOutlet var AlertView: UIView! //Alert View storyboard outlet

       override func viewDidLoad() { 
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillShow), name: 
        UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
 }

@objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification){

        guard let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue else {
           // if keyboard size is not available for some reason, don't do anything
           return
        }

        let keyBoardTop = self.view.frame.height - keyboardSize.height
        let bottomOfAlertView = AlertView.convert(AlertView.bounds, to: self.view).maxY;

        print("keyBoardTop: \(keyBoardTop)")
        print("BottomOfAlertView: \(bottomOfAlertView)")
        print(AlertView.frame.origin.y)

        AlertView.frame.origin.y = AlertView.frame.origin.y - (bottomOfAlertView - keyBoardTop)

    }
}
```

[Img Correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/71gcZ.png)

[Img Alert after typing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5jC30.png)

Answer (score 0):

What about trying to change the bottom constraint of the alert like this

```
@objc func handleShowKeyboard(_ notification: Notification) {
    if let keyboardFrame: NSValue = notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue {
        let keyboardRectangle = keyboardFrame.cgRectValue
        let keyboardOffset = keyboardRectangle.height
        if AlertView.viewBottomAnchor.constant == 0 {
            AlertView.viewBottomAnchor.constant -= (keyboardOffset - self.view.safeAreaInsets.bottom)
            AlertView.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
}
```